# Retrieve last two week's data from MYSQL excluding this week

Tags: mysql, date

i am looking to retrieve last two week's data from MYSQL excluding this week's data.

for example if today is mon - friday, query should return previous two weeks record.
            if today is either saturday or sunday, query should return records for this week + last week's  records.

did some search on and found that YEARweek could be useful but couldn't find the way to implement.

Comment: by week, do you mean actual week or 7 days from now, no matter what day now is ?

Comment: What are you asking for? The example you have given does not clarify much - in both cases you say "_query should return previous two weeks record_". Could you clarify exactly which dates it should return? "_last two week's data from MYSQL excluding this week's data_" means you really want **previous week's data** - is that correct?

Comment: if today is saturday - query should return records from previous week's monday upto yesterday; if today is between mon - friday; query should return from last two pervious week's data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have records on Saturday and Sunday. This should works fine.

```
where case 
when weekday(now()) between 0 and 4 then 
record_date between date_sub( date_sub(now(),INTERVAL weekday(now())+1 day),INTERVAL 2 WEEK) and  date_sub(now(),INTERVAL weekday(now())+1 day)
else
record_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK) and  now()
end
```